# How to match a color from an external image

Tags: materials

How do I use a color in an image of a photograph (.jpg file) as the base color for a material to apply.
When I select the 'eyedropper' I can only select from something in the work area of my Blender object but I want to use a color from an image of a photograph.

Comment: You could import your image as a plane (so it's in your viewport) then use the eyedropper on it.

Comment: I didn't know about that. I had to ensure 'Import-Export:Import images as planes' (addons) was selected/ticked then its as simple as select Add > Image > Image as Plane and then navigate to the file and select it as you would know but something new for me.  Thanks heaps.

Comment: If you open your image into a Blender image editor window you can use the eyedropper on it.

Comment: @joshsanfelici Just my thought. No need for the addon, although I recommend enabling it.

Comment: Sorry Gordon I have forgotten how to reply to a particular comment so that person gets an alert that there has been a reply. Is it typing @ symbole followed by the persons name. I thought that it could have been simpler. Please refresh my mind.   I would like to know if there are any disadvantages in having too many 'addons ticked'.

Comment: @JohnArnold Hey John, yes it's @ and then followed by the name without spaces inbetween. Usually these addressing gets automatically deleted if you comment on someone's question or answer when you address the author of that answer or question directly because they get notifications anyway. Well, the disadvantages depend on what your computer is capable of. As a general rule I can only say, the more addons are enabled, the more things are slowing down your startup of Blender and they might use some memory while you're working. But complex scenes are more demanding I would suspect.